# Copying from Chrome to OneNote Changes Font Style attributes

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-onenote

When I copy text from Chrome and paste it in OneNote it changes the font size from 20 to 15 and the line spacing (Line Height) from 29 to 24 although I pasted it choosing keep source formatting.

This is how the website looks in Chrome:

[image: Chrome window]

Here is how it appeared when I pasted it into OneNote with "keep source formatting" option:

[image: OneNote window]

You notice that the font size and line height have changed to lower numbers, I don't know why.

My screen resolution is 1366×768 and scaling is set to 100%.
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: For *"Troubleshooting 101"* purposes, have you tested the same procedure using a different browser (Firefox or IE) as your source?

Comment: It has been several days since your original question, and you haven't provided us with any feedback. Did you have any lingering questions?

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome text content is probably stored as "rich text" on the clipboard, which for our purposes is basically HTML formatting.

The font size information probably preserves some, but not all, of the formatting information; I'm not sure there's anything you can do to change it. Maybe change the initial font in OneNote, before pasting?